# Cordova plugin with Cocoapod dependency is not working properly

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, swift3, cocoapods

I am new to Cordova plugin implementation. I am creating a Cordova plugin that provides Web Socket support to the Cordova App.

For Android platform everything is working fine. But for iOS, using Swift, I am stuck.

For iOS (using Swift), to work with WebSocket, I am using **SwiftWebSocket** client library. I have added this pod dependency to my plugin.xml file as below -

`<framework src="SwiftWebSocket" type="podspec" spec="~> 2.6.4" />`

I have created cordova application and to provide Swift support I have already added below plugin to it -

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support --save
```

After adding this plugin, I have added my local plugin to it. I can successfully install my **Podfile** and I can view "SwiftWebSocket" within generated Pods folder. My application is successfully built.

Problem is, when I am trying to -

`import SwiftWebSocket`

I am getting an error stating "No such module SwiftWebSocket". Please note that, I have already added **all Pod Projects** using **Manage Schemes** and built them successfully. But still I am getting same error.

If anyone has implemented cordova plugin with POD dependency, please let me know if any specific **build settings** that I have to do for resolving such issue or if I am missing something.

Comment: I got the same issue, when trying to integrate `TesseractOCRiOS` pod into Cordova created Xcode project. `import TesseractOCR` is not working for me. Please help me if you figure out anything.

Answer (score 0):

Swift pods need to be used as frameworks, for that, you will need `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile, but the Podfile Cordova uses doesn't contain that line.

You can try to add that line manually in `projectName/platforms/ios/Podfile`, but there is no guarantee that it will work.

I created [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11893) long time ago, but no work has been done about it as `use_frameworks!` can cause incompatibility problems with Cordova.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's true and I did exactly in same way - adding that line manually and it is working properly. My 'pod install' command is working and Pods project gets successfully added to my Cordova application.